# chart.js on animation end callback

Tags: javascript, html, animation, chart.js, vue.js

Does the library [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) support any sort of callbacks on specific events? I'm mostly interested in *'on animation end'* event, but would be nice to know any other events if they're supported.
If this is not an option, do you know any workarounds? I'm using **jQuery** and **vue.js** and I just need to show some additional text on the page (completely outside of the chart itself) when **chart.js** finishes the animation of the chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an onAnimationComplete option you can specify to run stuff once the animation completes. See [this section](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration) of the documentation.

Example

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
var myLine1 = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData1, {
    onAnimationComplete: function() {
        alert('animation complete')
    }
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4vo72rLd/

Comment: and if I only want to run it the first time the graph renders?

Answer (score 8):

> For Chart.Js 2.6.0

```
options: {
    cutoutPercentage: 90,
    animation: {
        duration: 2000,
        onProgress: function(animation) {
            $progress.attr({
                value: animation.animationObject.currentStep / animation.animationObject.numSteps,
            });
        },
        onComplete: function(animation) {
            alert('onAnimationComplete')
        }
    }
},
```

See this codepen https://codepen.io/shivabhusal/pen/XaZQaW