# How do you get the width of a datalabel from the Chartjs plugin after the chart animates?

Tags: chart.js

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/thoughtassassin/pen/KKQZEXN?editors=1010) that I am using to solve this problem. What I would like to do is get the length of the horizontal bars to determine if the label should be plotted inside or outside of the bar. Currently, what I have happening:

```
{
  datalabels: {
    color: function(context) {
      return [0, 3].includes(context.dataIndex) ? 'black' : 'white'
    },
    anchor: 'start',
    align: 'right',
    offset: function(context) {
      const chart = context.chart;
      const area = chart.chartArea;
      const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(context.datasetIndex);
      const model = meta.data[context.dataIndex];
      // model.width is NaN
      // is there a way to get this value
      // after the animation is complete?
      console.log(model, model.width)
      return 4;
    },
    font: {
      size: 9
    }
  }
```

When you run the codepen you notice that model.width prints as NaN but when you look at the object itself model.width is there. If I introduce a setTimeout to log that value it exists (not NaN). When I turn the animation off model.width is available in the function.

Therefore, I think the way to make this happen is to get the values after the animation renders. Is there a way to do that in the offset function for datalabels or is there another way of doing that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chart.js on animation end callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084587/chart-js-on-animation-end-callback)

Comment: It does not. I believe LeeLenalee is exactly what I was looking for. I tried the onComplete method and it didn't do exactly what I was wanting. I needed to get the width of the offset scriptable function so I could calculate and set the offset there.

You'll probably also noticed that I discovered a better way of achieving what I wanted. I think this question is still useful because someone may need to modify the offset of a datalabel based upon the width of bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getProps` on the model to get the width after the animations are over like so:

```js
offset: function(context) {
  const chart = context.chart;
  const area = chart.chartArea;
  const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(context.datasetIndex);
  const model = meta.data[context.dataIndex];
  const {
    width
  } = model.getProps(['width'], true);
  console.log(width)
  return 4;
},
```

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/leelenaleee/pen/MWQGbdM?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

I might have been thinking about it the wrong way. By playing around with the values I realized the value itself is a pretty good indication of whether it should be inside or outside of the bar. What I've done instead is evaluate if the value is greater than 30. If so the color is white and the anchor is set to start. If it less than 30 the color is black and the anchor is set to end:

https://codepen.io/thoughtassassin/pen/rNJvOrj

```
plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      color: (context) => getValue(context) > 30 ? '#fff' : '#000',
      anchor: (context) => getValue(context) > 30 ? 'start' : 'end',
      align: 'right',
      offset: 5,
      font: {
        size: 9
      }
    },
  }
```